# Importing contacts and their relationships

Tags: contacts, relationships

this is really two questions, but may be answered via the first.

Q1: I have a large set of contacts (1400+) in a spreadsheet that already has a column for organisation (or household).  ie First name, Last Name, Organisation
When I go to import the contacts csv how can I auto-create the organisation contact and have the relationship set up so that an imported contact has the "Member of" relationship.
I have looked at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Importing+Households+and+Household+Members

But i am not 100% clear on the instructions - is it saying to upload the Organisations first, then upload the members of the organisation

Q2:  if Q1 is not possible/practical or having imported contacts already that may not have existing relationship data, how can i bulk updated select/filtered contacts to add a relationship in one pass as doing them individually would be a very time consuming and error prone process.

Comment: I have found my solution to Q2.
Search (top left)
-> Advanced Search
----> Address Fields:  City = 'some city"
note: i added the organisation name as the city when imported but I cant do a wildcard search on only part of the city name it has to be an exact match - not a biggy)

-->'Actions --> Add to {Household|Organisation}

Answer (score 1):

If your csv includes eg First, Last and Organisation, then in the mapping, way way down the bottom, you will see the options to set the organisation field to map to something like 'relationship, employer of' and then choose eg 'organisation name' and that should take care of it.

Comment: Thanks @petednz
Got it working "Employee of, Organization Name (Match to contact)***"

But there is no option in the drop-down to also add the start-end dates or the Status: Enabled|Disabled during the import.